# .net operator overloading??? type conversion operator, how exactly it works?

Tags: .net, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

I have first encounter operator overloading in .Net, long back I had used it in C++, but that was like overloading operators like "+", now I have suddenly scenario as below.

I have a struct `AccessToken`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct AccessToken : IConvertible
{
    private string _value;
    public AccessToken(string encodedAccessToken)
    {
        this._value = encodedAccessToken;
    }

    public static implicit operator AccessToken(string encodedAccessToken)
    {
        return new AccessToken(encodedAccessToken);
    }
}
```

I understood the first method is a constructor, but I was wondering exactly 2nd one is doing? Definitely some kind of operator overloading. I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3(v=vs.71).aspx but could not get exact idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an implicit conversion from `string` to `AccessToken`. So you could write:

```
string foo = "asdasd";
AccessToken token = foo;
```

That would invoke the second member - the implicit conversion operator. Without that being present, the above code wouldn't compile, as there would be no conversion available from `string` to `AccessToken`.

Personally I would advise you to be *very* careful with implicit conversions - they can make code much harder to understand. Just *occasionally* they can be very useful (LINQ to XML springs to mind) but I would normally just go with constructors or static factory methods.

Comment: To do something like this "AccessToken token = foo" I thought we have to overload = operator.

Comment: @Pritesh You can't overload `=` in C#. And it's something different anyways. It also allows you to pass a string to a method which has an `AccessToken` as parameter.

Comment: @Pritesh: You shouldn't infer anything about Google's use of technologies from my hobbies. What were you thinking about in particular?

Comment: @CodeInChaos I was wondering when we do "string foo = "asdasd"; actually something like this has happend. string foo = new string("asdasd"); so inside .net framework  implicit conversion operator is define for string class??

Comment: @Pritesh: No, string literals are defined as part of the C# language and constant strings embedded directly into IL are supported by the CLR. If there were an implicit conversion operator in use there, what type would you expect the operand to be?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am a bit confuse. when we do string foo = "asdasd"; a new instance of string is created i.e. new string("asdasd") and it's refrence is attached to variable???

Comment: @codeinchaos a bit more help. What exactly this is doing??
        
public static explicit operator DateTime(XDateTime emptyDateTime)
        {
            if (emptyDateTime.IsEmpty)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DateTime is Empty");
            }
            return emptyDateTime.dateTime;
        }

Comment: @Pritesh: It sounds like you should be asking two more questions... but using a string literal *doesn't* always create a new string object, and the explicit operator is just one which you use via casting - e.g. `DateTime x = (DateTime) someXDateTime;`

Answer (score 0):

The implicit operator allows you to assign an instance of type `A` to type `B` with a conversion defined in type `A`.

It can simplify your code a bit since you don't have to call conversion methods etc but can type `B b = new A();` even though `A` doesn't inherit `B`.

I think it tends to introduce confusion though and prefer more explicit casts and conversions.

Comment: a bit more help. What exactly this is doing??
        
public static explicit operator DateTime(XDateTime emptyDateTime)
        {
            if (emptyDateTime.IsEmpty)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DateTime is Empty");
            }
            return emptyDateTime.dateTime;
        }

Comment: It will convert a `XDateTime` to `DateTime` using the `dateTime` field on the `XDateTime` object passed (or throw exception if the `XDateTime` is null.)
It would allow assignments like `DateTime dt = new XDateTime xdt();`